# VHDL: Std_Logic input stored in integer issue

Tags: events, vector, integer, vhdl, bit

I have the following problem:

I have a PC which gives inputs to my SPARTAN 3AN FPGA and I wish to fetch those inputs, put them in a std_logic_vector, then convert them into integer. The instructions are divided in "n" instructions with 32 bits each. I need the first three bits be put in one integer, the next 28 in another, and the last is a "Last instruction flag". So, I have two arrays of 100 integers in which I would be putting the instructions (100 is the limit). If the "Last instruction flag" is one, than the entire operation should stop.

The program didn't synthesize properly, so I made a simulation of it. And I found the problem, but I don't know how to solve it, so I need your help. Here is the code and the simulation output:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;


entity BinaryDecimalConv is
end BinaryDecimalConv;

architecture Behavioral of BinaryDecimalConv is

    type int_array is array (100 downto 0) of integer;

    signal clkcnt: integer :=0;
    signal fbaud: integer;
    signal lastnumflag: std_logic:='0';
    signal clk: std_logic;
    signal PLCinput: std_logic;
    signal init: std_logic;
    signal BusyIN: std_logic;
    signal BusyOutSignal: std_logic;
    signal InnerBusyOut: std_logic;
    signal cnt: integer :=0;
    signal fbaut: integer :=0;
    signal pre_int: std_logic_vector (31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal pre_spec_num: int_array := (others =>0);
    signal cylinder: int_array := (others => 0);
    signal InnerNumLength: integer:=0;
    signal num_length: integer:=0;

begin

CLOCKK: Process is
begin
    clk<='0';
    wait for 10 ns;
    clk<='1';
    wait for 10 ns;
end process CLOCKK;

fbaud <=5208;
BusyIN <='0';
init <='0';

PLC: Process is
    variable PrePLC: std_logic_vector(159 downto 0):="1010101010101010101010101001010010101010101010101010101010010100101010101010101010101010100101001010101010101010101010101001010010101010101010101010101010010101"; -- 1 with 100, 5 with 200, 5 2ith 200, 3 with 300, 4 with 750
begin
    PLCinput<=PrePLC(159);
    PrePLC:= PrePLC(158 downto 1) & '0';
    wait for 104166 ns;
end process;    


LastNum: process (LastNumFlag) is
    begin
    if LastNumFlag = '1' then
        BusyOutSignal <='1';
        InnerBusyOut <='1';
    else
        BusyOutSignal <='0';
        InnerBusyOut <='0';
    end if;
    end process LastNum;

DecoderAndAcquirer: process (PLCinput, BusyIN, InnerBusyOut,clk) is
begin

    if (clk'event and clk='1') then                                                         -- If rising edge on clock
        if ((BusyIN='0') and (InnerBusyOut='0') and (init='0')) then                        -- Check if FPGA and PLC are ready to exchange information and if init is done
            if (clkcnt = fbaud/2)                    then                                   --  If clkcnt is equal to half of the duration of the input bit then
                pre_int(31) <= PLCinput;                                                    -- Initialize the last digit of pre_int
                cnt <= cnt+1;                                                               -- Incrementing cnt => going towards bit 2
                clkcnt <=clkcnt+1;                                                          -- Incrementing clkcnt so you can exit this block
                if (cnt<32) then                                                            -- Checking if not last bit
                    pre_int <= '0' & pre_int(31 downto 1);                                  -- If not last bit, shift number to right
                else                                                                        -- else
                    cnt <=0;                                                                -- reset cnt to start with next instruction
                    if (pre_int(0)='1') then                                                -- Check if last digit is one
                        LastNumFlag <= '1';                                                 -- If last digit is one, stop acquiring instructions
                    else
                        LastNumFlag <='0';
                    end if;
                    pre_spec_num(InnerNumLength) <= to_integer(unsigned(pre_int(28 downto 1))); -- Conversion from binary to decimal for instruction
                    cylinder(InnerNumLength) <= to_integer(unsigned(pre_int(31 downto 29)));    -- Conversion from binary to decimal for the number of cylinder
                    InnerNumLength <= InnerNumLength +1;                                            -- Incrementing the number of instructions
                    num_length <= InnerNumLength;
                end if;
            elsif (clkcnt = fbaud) then                                                     -- If clkcnt has reached the entire length of the input bit
                clkcnt <= 0;                                                                -- set clkcnt to zero so the process can start from beginning.
            else                                                                            -- If clkcnt is less than or more than half of the entire duration, but surely
                clkcnt <= clkcnt +1;                                                        -- less than the entire duration, then increment the value of the clkcnt.
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process DecoderAndAcquirer;

end Behavioral;
```

The thing is that, as shown on the picture, when cnt changes, nothing happens to the 31st bit of the instruction. Any ideas why?

Thanks,
Bojan

[image: Simulation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `PrePLC := PrePLC(158 downto 1) & '0';` mismatches length, so I assume
this is to be `PrePLC := PrePLC(158 downto 0) & '0';` instead, thus working as
shift register.

In process DecoderAndAcquirer of the code there is:

```
...
pre_int(31) <= PLCinput;
...
if (cnt<32) then
  pre_int <= '0' & pre_int(31 downto 1);
...
```

So even through `pre_int(31)` is assigned, it is later overwritten in the
`pre_int <= '0' & pre_int(31 downto 1);` since `(cnt<32)`, whereby the
pre_int(31) cant go high yet.

When simulating longer time, cnt goes to 32, and then the an '1' value is shown at pre_int(31); se figure below.

[image]

Edited: Below is version with temporary variable for pre_int, just to show the principles; operation is not verified.

```
DecoderAndAcquirer: process (PLCinput, BusyIN, InnerBusyOut,clk) is
  variable pre_int_v : std_logic_vector(pre_int'range);
begin

    if (clk'event and clk='1') then                                                         -- If rising edge on clock
        pre_int_v := pre_int;  -- Variable update from signal
        if ((BusyIN='0') and (InnerBusyOut='0') and (init='0')) then                        -- Check if FPGA and PLC are ready to exchange information and if init is done
            if (clkcnt = fbaud/2)                    then                                   --  If clkcnt is equal to half of the duration of the input bit then
                pre_int_v(31) := PLCinput;                                                    -- Initialize the last digit of pre_int
                cnt <= cnt+1;                                                               -- Incrementing cnt => going towards bit 2
                clkcnt <=clkcnt+1;                                                          -- Incrementing clkcnt so you can exit this block
                if (cnt<32) then                                                            -- Checking if not last bit
                    pre_int_v := '0' & pre_int_v(31 downto 1);                                  -- If not last bit, shift number to right
                else                                                                        -- else
                    cnt <=0;                                                                -- reset cnt to start with next instruction
                    if (pre_int_v(0)='1') then                                                -- Check if last digit is one
                        LastNumFlag <= '1';                                                 -- If last digit is one, stop acquiring instructions
                    else
                        LastNumFlag <='0';
                    end if;
                    pre_spec_num(InnerNumLength) <= to_integer(unsigned(pre_int_v(28 downto 1))); -- Conversion from binary to decimal for instruction
                    cylinder(InnerNumLength) <= to_integer(unsigned(pre_int_v(31 downto 29)));    -- Conversion from binary to decimal for the number of cylinder
                    InnerNumLength <= InnerNumLength +1;                                            -- Incrementing the number of instructions
                    num_length <= InnerNumLength;
                end if;
            elsif (clkcnt = fbaud) then                                                     -- If clkcnt has reached the entire length of the input bit
                clkcnt <= 0;                                                                -- set clkcnt to zero so the process can start from beginning.
            else                                                                            -- If clkcnt is less than or more than half of the entire duration, but surely
                clkcnt <= clkcnt +1;                                                        -- less than the entire duration, then increment the value of the clkcnt.
            end if;
        end if;
        pre_int <= pre_int_v;  -- Signals update from variable
    end if;
end process DecoderAndAcquirer;
```

Figure with waveform is shown below.

[image]

Comment: Yes, for the first one, you are right. I've missed one bit (how come it does simulates it, though?). For the second: I do wish to overwrite it. Since, PLCinputs will be arriving every 104166 ns and I wish them to be shifted to the right, so even if it doesn't show it's value at the moment when it acquires a value, it should show preint(30) as a 1, because I actually did pre_int(30) <= pre_int(31) when I shifted it to the right. Let's say it's first iteration and i have 00000000000000000000000000000000, then, when PLCinput arrives, it becomes 10000000000000000000000000000000.

Comment: When I use pre_int <= '0' & pre_int(31 downto 1), I cut one zero from the end, making it 1000000000000000000000000000000, and adding zero in the front, making it 01000000000000000000000000000000. So this should appear on the plot. Shouldn't it?

Comment: For the first one: ModelSim reports error due to the length mismatch, so sounds like your simulator ain't picky enough.  For the second: I have added figure that shows pre_int(31) as '1' after longer simulation, so cnt get to 32.  For you last comment: No, the first `pre_int(31) <= PLCinput;` does not have any effect, since the signal assignment `<=` does not alter the signal value before next simulation cycle, so the subsequent `pre_int <= '0' & pre_int(31 downto 1)` will use the current value of pre_int, resulting in all 0's.

Comment: For the second: My simulator too shows one after 32 iterations, but that's not the behavior I am willing to get. I need it to change instantly, as soon as PLCinput gets a new value. In the original project (not the simulation one) i use variable for that cause, just because signals changes value after delta cycle. I used signals here because my simulator won't allow me to simulate variables, but at the point of writing the simulation project, I totally forgot about the signals and their assignment. But, my point is that I tried this even with variables. It still gives some weird number on exit

Comment: "So even through pre_int(31) is assigned, it is later overwritten in the pre_int <= '0' & pre_int(31 downto 1); since (cnt<32), whereby the pre_int(31) cant go high yet."  There is no intervening passage of simulation time (no wait for, wait on, wait until).  You have a current signal value and a next signal value.  You traverse sequential statements before the delta cycle proceeds and update (overwrite) the next signal value, erasing the first write to pre_int(31).

Comment: Yes, yes. I understand David. I am pretty new to VHDL and sometimes forget those things. But, the point is that even with variables - it doesn't work! :(

Comment: @Бојан Другар Матовски: See update in answer for version with temporary variable; as I noted, then correct operation is not verified, so it servers as an example only.